Avoid the duplication in the script
The code below is duplicated twice in the full script, how to avoid it?
        if jurge_expr ; then
            (( retry_cnt += 1 ))
            echo $CS2
            echo "reading CS2 checking failed. retry, retry_cnt=$retry_cnt"
            if [[ $retry_cnt -gt $max_retry_cnt ]]; then
                echo "$RED retry too many times, failed to write 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename $RESET"
                break;
            fi
            sleep 0.5
            continue;
        fi

Here is the full script:
# Loop through each filename in sorted_files and print it
set -- $sorted_files
for filename; do
    addr=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f1)
    bytes=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f2 | sed -e 's/B.dat//' -e 's/KB.dat//')
    
    retry_cnt=0;
    while true; 
    do
        echo "bulk writing 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename"
        ccidbgr /dev/cci2 0x6d bulkWrite 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename
        sleep 0.5
        echo "reading CS2"
        CS2=$(ccidbgr /dev/cci2 0x6d read 0xF2 2>&1)
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
            (( retry_cnt += 1 ))
            echo $CS2
            echo "reading CS2 checking failed. retry, retry_cnt=$retry_cnt"
            if [[ $retry_cnt -gt $max_retry_cnt ]]; then
                echo "$RED retry too many times, failed to write 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename $RESET"
                break;
            fi
            sleep 0.5
            continue;
        fi
        
        echo $CS2
        CS2=$(echo $CS2 | cut -dx -f3)
        if [[ $CS2 -eq 0 ]]; then
            (( retry_cnt += 1 ))
            echo "read CS2 is zero. retry, retry_cnt=$retry_cnt"
                if [[ $retry_cnt -gt $max_retry_cnt ]]; then
                echo "$RED retry too many times, failed to write 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename $RESET"
                break;
            fi
            sleep 0.5
            continue;
        fi
    done
done



What speaks against putting it into a function?

@user1934428 The @Ivan's answer mentions function, but I am not sure the break in function could stop the outer loop. See my comment for the said anwer for details.

From the viewpoint of design, a function should never decide on its own that a loop invoking the function should be terminated. In programming, we either return a code to the caller and let the caller decide what to do in this case, or maybe rise an exception (or, in some languages, use a continuation). In ksh, the code can be returned as exit code (using the return statment), and an exception could be simulated by kill (which the caller then needs to trap). There are no continuations in ksh. I'm pretty sure that the return code variant will give you the least headache.

BTW, don't use the function keyword -- it's a holdout from 1980s ksh syntax that bash supports only for backwards compatibility. Without it, a function is just a function, not a function. :)

For this particular case I'd probably merge the two (almost) duplicate blocks of code into a single block, using a few new variables to help with logic flow.
One idea:
set -- $sorted_files
for filename; do
    addr=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f1)
    bytes=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f2 | sed -e 's/B.dat//' -e 's/KB.dat//')
    
    retry_cnt=0;
    while true; 
    do
        echo "bulk writing 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename"
        ccidbgr /dev/cci2 0x6d bulkWrite 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename
        sleep 0.5
        echo "reading CS2"
        CS2=$(ccidbgr /dev/cci2 0x6d read 0xF2 2>&1)

        ###################################### new/replacement code (start)

        rc=$?                                   # save return code
        IFS='x' read -ra cval <<< "$CS2"        # split CS2 on delimiter "x" into array cval[]
        msg=""                                  # clear msg

        # test two new vars (rc, cval[2])

        [[ "$rc"        -ne 0 ]] && { echo "$CS2"; msg="reading CS2 checking failed. retry, retry_cnt=$retry_cnt"; }
        [[ "${cval[2]}" -eq 0 ]] && {              msg="read CS2 is zero. retry, retry_cnt=$retry_cnt"           ; }

        if [[ -n "$msg" ]]                      # if msg is not empty then one of the 2 tests was 'true' so ...
        then
            (( retry_cnt++ ))
            echo "$msg"
            if [[ $retry_cnt -gt $max_retry_cnt ]]; then
                echo "$RED retry too many times, failed to write 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename $RESET"
                break;
            fi
            sleep 0.5
            continue;
        fi

        ###################################### new/replacement code (end)

    done
done

NOTES: I don't have the environment to put this code through a test run but shellcheck.net doesn't report any syntax errors

Function? Consider this:
...
fun(){
    (( retry_cnt += 1 ))
    echo $CS2
    echo "reading CS2 checking failed. retry, retry_cnt=$retry_cnt"
    if [[ $retry_cnt -gt $max_retry_cnt ]]; then
        echo "$RED retry too many times, failed to write 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename $RESET"
        return 1
    fi
    sleep 0.5
    return 2
}
...
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && { fun; case $? in 1) break;; 2) continue;; esac;}
...
[[ $CS2 -eq 0 ]] && { fun; case $? in 1) break;; 2) continue;; esac;}
...

Or like this:
...
fun(){
    (( retry_cnt += 1 ))
    echo $CS2
    echo "reading CS2 checking failed. retry, retry_cnt=$retry_cnt"
    if [[ $retry_cnt -gt $max_retry_cnt ]]; then
        echo "$RED retry too many times, failed to write 0xe2 $bytes 2 $filename $RESET"
        return 0
    fi
    sleep 0.5
    return 1
}
...
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && { fun && break || continue ;}
...
[[ $CS2 -eq 0 ]] && { fun && break || continue ;}
...

This one looks better.

In my code snippet, break is used to stop the while loop. If break is encapsulated in func(), the  outer while loop could be still stopped?

@John yes you are right, return must be used in this case, and there is also continue... Not fun at all)

Updated with return but it looks ugly)
